# How does a sine function solve an Euler equation (rSLP)?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

I'm currently trying to solve an rSLP which looks like this (Euler equation):
$$x^2f''(x)+xf'(x)+cf(x)=0,\ f(1)=f'(2)=0,\ x\in [1,2] \text{ and }c\neq0.$$
It's simple that $f(x)=x^{\pm\sqrt{-c}}$ solves the equation for $c\neq0$. By theorem, $\{x^{\sqrt{-c}},x^{-\sqrt{-c}}\}$ will be a basis for solutions to the equation. This means that all solutions can be written as a linear comb. of of the basis:
$$f(x)=Ax^{\sqrt{-c}}+Bx^{\sqrt{-c}}=Ae^{ln(x)\sqrt{-c}}+Be^{-ln(x)\sqrt{-c}}.$$
First boundary condition: $f(1)=0\Leftrightarrow A=-B\ \Rightarrow \ f(x)=e^{ln(x)\sqrt{-c}}-e^{-ln(x)\sqrt{-c}} \text{ up to some constant.}$

The second BC: $f'(2)=0$. Derivative is
$$f'(x)=\frac{\sqrt{-c}}{r}e^{ln(x)\sqrt{-c}}+\frac{\sqrt{-c}}{r}e^{-ln(x)\sqrt{-c}}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 \frac{\sqrt{c}}{r}\text{cos}(ln(x)\sqrt{c}),& c>0\\ 
 \frac{\sqrt{-c}}{r}\text{cosh}(ln(x)\sqrt{-c}),& c<0 
\end{matrix}\right. \text{ (again up to constants)}.$$
Since $\text{cosh}(x)\neq0 \text{ and }c\neq0$ we can tell that $c>0 $ and that $f'(x)=\frac{\sqrt{c}}{r}\text{cos}(ln(x)\sqrt{c})$ which also implies that $f(x)=\text{sin}(ln(x)\sqrt{c})$ up to some constant. So $f'(2)=0$:
$$f'(2)=\frac{\sqrt{c}}{2}\text{cos}(ln(2)\sqrt{c})=0\ \Leftrightarrow \ \text{cos}(ln(2)\sqrt{c})=0\ \Leftrightarrow \ c=\frac{\pi^2(2n+1)^2}{4(ln(2))^2}.$$
So we have the eigenfunctions $\{\text{sin}(\frac{\pi(2n+1)}{2ln(2)}ln(x))\}_{n\geq 1}$ with eigenvalues $\frac{\pi^2(2n+1)^2}{4(ln(2))^2}$ to this regular SLP.

HOWEVER, what I don't understand is that if you put in $f_n(x)=\text{sin}(\frac{\pi(2n+1)}{2ln(2)}ln(x))$ in the Euler equation which we are solving, the $f_n(x)$ term and the $f_n''(x)$ term will cancel each other out. Then we are left with the equation $$\frac{\pi(2n+1)}{2ln(2)}\text{cos}(\frac{\pi(2n+1)}{2ln(2)}ln(x))=0.$$
This is obviously not true for all $x\in [1,2]$. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: The two terms don’t cancel.

Comment: Oh my... I didn't think about the 1/x you get from the first derivative. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homogeneous equation $x^2f''(x) + xf'(x) + cf(x) = 0$
on $1 < x < 2$ has solution
\begin{equation*}
 f(x) =
 \begin{cases}
  A\cos(\sqrt{c}\log x) + B\sin(\sqrt{c}\log x) & \text{  $c > 0$}, \\
  A\cosh(\sqrt{-c}\log x) + B\sinh(\sqrt{-c}\log x) & \text{  $c < 0$}, \\
  A\log x + B & \text{  $c = 0$}.
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
The boundary conditions $f(1) = f'(2) = 0$ constrain nontrivial solutions. Simple substitution shows
$A$ and $B$ must vanish in the $c = 0$ case, so we'll ignore it.
In the other two cases the condition $f(1) = 0$ requires $A = 0$, so
\begin{equation*}
 f(x) =
 \begin{cases}
  B\sin(\sqrt{c}\log x) & \text{  $c > 0$}, \\
  B\sinh(\sqrt{-c}\log x) & \text{  $c < 0$}. \\
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
The condition $f'(2) = 0$ cannot be satisfied by the second, so we're left with the
restriction that $c > 0$ and $\sqrt{c}\log 2 = (2n+1)\pi/2$ for $n=0, 1, \dots$.